# Web UI with Intellisense

Tags: java, user-interface, autocomplete, web, intellisense

I want to develop a Web UI in J2EE environment. That is responsible for rule creation base on some syntax grammar. I want to add **intellisense** while writing a rule in text box.That is, It should assist the user while typing the rule and should predict what next possible inputs user can write.Is there any library or framework in java or java-script that could help me out on this?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for some sort of autocomplete via ajax. The client can send a partial string to the server via ajax, and the server can interrogate and respond with choices of commands.

I would suggest looking into the jquery ui autocomplete framework